# How to read digitalout with Jamod?

Tags: java, modbus

i have set the digital in in the server:

```
SimpleDigitalOut dout1;
dout1 = new SimpleDigitalOut(true);
```

how can i read digitalin in the master class with jamod?

only i can read is the simpleRegister.
thank you!

Comment: anyone can help i need it too